# Prevenir Abuso De Un Script PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo este código **php** que funciona correctamente pero tiene un error.

Este script fue diseñado para que los usuarios puedan obtener regalos gifts gratis virtual en mi web, pero cuando los usuarios le dan click varias veces seguidas con saldo de oro el script les da mas de lo que pueden obtener y por lo tanto tienen oro negativo, osea que hay un bug.

Pero cuando lo intentas sin saldo de oro virtual no hay problemas, mi pregunta es, **¿cómo puedo hacer para que no obtengan mas gifts del que pueden obtener?** osea que el script ponga una pausa cuando detecte que el usuario ya no tiene oro y no puede seguir comprando

aqui les dejo el código:

```
<form name="advanceplus" method="post">

            <tr height="50">

                <td></td>

                <td class="desc"><b>Buy Gift:</b> ';

                    echo '<select name="giftqty" onchange="return gift_res(this.value,'.$qty_gold.')">';

                    echo '<option value=1>100,000</option>



                    </select>

                    <img class="r1" src="img/x.gif" alt="Lumber" title="Lumber" /> <img class="r2" src="img/x.gif" alt="Clay" title="Clay" /> <img class="r3" src="img/x.gif" alt="Iron" title="Iron" /> <img class="r4" src="img/x.gif" alt="Crop" title="Crop" /></td>

                    <span class="run"></span>



                    <td class="dur">Now</td>

                <td class="cost"><img src="img/x.gif" class="gold" alt="Gold" title="Gold" /><span id="qtyres">30</span></td>

               <td class="act"><span id="buygift">';
if($golds['gold'] > 29) {
    echo '
        <a href="#" onclick="return go_submit(1)">Buy';
} else {
    echo '<a href="plus.php"><span class="none">too little gold';
}
echo '</span></a>';
echo '
</td>
</tr>';
```

En esta parte del codigo se le indica al script que no puede seguir dando mas gifts de lo que el usuario puede comprar, osea que con una cantidad menor a 30 monedas de oro no deberia de dar gifts:

```
if($golds['gold'] > 29) {
    echo '
        <a href="#" onclick="return go_submit(1)">Buy';
} else {
    echo '<a href="plus.php"><span class="none">too little gold';
```

Pero no se porque no funciona, que necesito agregar a este codigo php?, si alguien me puede ayudar le estaria muy agradecido! Feliz nuevo dia!

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. No se si estás omitiendo las etiquetas de apertura y de cierre de script, me refiero a algo así: `<?php if ($golds...   ?>`.  Estas etiquetas son necesarias cuando quieres incluir código PHP dentrop de código HTML. https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php. Además de eso, ¿que impediría que un usuario espabilado llamase a go_submit(1) desde la consola del navegador? Esa comprobación del oro a lo mejor debería estar en otro lugar.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la ayuda, osea que debo de colocar <?php ?> al principio y final del script?, mi pregunta es porque sigue dando mas gift de lo que el usuario puede comprar con su saldo?, de nuevo muchas gracias! osea que es una injeccion sql por que yo lo he probado y es verdad, cuando yo coloque este script no me fije que habia ese bug hasta que empeze a ver usuarios con saldo negativo de oro y le propuse a un usuario darle 5000 monedas de oro si me decia con que programa lo habia hecho y me sorprendi cuando el me dijo que solo tenia que apretar seguidamente el boton de "Buy" lol

Comment: Hola alguien que pueda ayudar por favor!!